# MySQL order issue

Tags: mysql

Have a table with events results - winner, loser, location, date, round. Want to output a player's best result at the event (and the 2nd ordering would be by date - so if he won in 2012 and 2014 it would list the 2012 win). The following query works but doesn't output a win of the event (W) if the player made the final and lost first (made the final in 2012 and lost but then won in 2015).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN win=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='f' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then 'W', los=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='f' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then 'F', los=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='sf' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then 'SF', los=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='qf' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then 'QF', los=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='2nd' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then '2nd', los=(select id players where last like concat('smith','%') AND first like concat('b','%')) AND 
  round='1st' AND tourn like concat('city','%')then '1st', end as round, date_format(thedate, '%Y') as 'theYear' from records order by field(round,'W','F','SF','QF','2nd','1st), thedate limit 1;
```

Comment: It's not possible to fathom what you're after from this mess. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

Replaced ORDER BY FIELD.  Used

```
order by CASE 
  WHEN round = 'W' THEN 0  
  WHEN round='F' THEN 1 
  WHEN round='SF' THEN 2
  etc
  END LIMIT 1
```

Comment: 'Select... where` Is invalid syntax, regardless of whatever else you do with it